# Magento 2.1 Hyphen in search

Tags: magento-2.1, search

Let's say I have products

- `abc_123_big`
- `abc_123_medium`
- `abc_123_small`
- `cba-321-small`
- `cba-321-medium`
- `cba-321-big`

When I search with query `abc_123_big`, I got `abc_123_big`. When I search with query `abc_123`, I got `abc_123_big` & `abc_123_medium` & `abc_123_small`. That's what I want.

But our products have hyphens in SKUs so when I search with query `cba-321-big`, I got `cba-321-small` & `cba-321-medium` & `cba-321-big` and all others product which have `cba` or `321` or `big` in SKUs.

Is it possible to get hyphen to act as like an underscore (to get exact matches) and not as an AND-splitter?

Comment: Just today saw the same issue. Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: @Taran Noup and I'm now using Mirasvit Sphinx Search Ultimate for Magento 2

Comment: anyone know how to solve this ?